# data is not inserting into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I'm thinking there is an issue with the serialization part of the jquery ajax. It's not putting any information into the database and I have no idea why! Obviously the variables from the input controls on the webpage are not being passed into the php processing page. What am I doing wrong here?? Need some help here with this folks! This is all very new to me.

Webpage:

```
 <form name="main_form" id="main_form" method="post">
    <div id="ChangeAddressDialog" title="Change of Address">
        <p>Mailing Address: <input type="text" id="Address1" name="Address1" /></p>
        <p>Mailing Address 2: <input type="text" id="Address2" name="Address2" /></p>
        <p>City: <input type="text" id="City" name="City" /></p>
        <p>State: <input type="text" id="State" name="State" maxlength="2" /></p>
        <p>Zip Code: <input type="text" id="Zip" id="Zip" maxlength="10" /></p>
        <p>Country: <input type="text" id="County" name="Country" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" id="change_of_address_form" name="change_of_address_form" />
    </div>
  </form>

    $('#ChangeOfAddress').click(function() {
        //change of address dialog
        $( "#ChangeAddressDialog" ).dialog({
            width:500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Ok", type: "submit", click: function() { 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "classes/add-address.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)

                            },
                            success: function(result){
                                //do stuff here on success such as modal info
                                //$("#main_form").submit();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        })
                    } 
                },
                { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });//end dialog
    });
```

PHP processing page:

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

//$sqlCheck = '';
$parcel_id = isset($_POST['ParcelId']) ? $_POST['ParcelId'] : null;
$address1 = isset($_POST['Address1']) ? $_POST['Address1'] : null;
$address2 = isset($_POST['Address2']) ? $_POST['Address2'] : null;
$city = isset($_POST['City']) ? $_POST['City'] : null;
$state = isset($_POST['State']) ? $_POST['State'] : null;
$zip = isset($_POST['Zip']) ? $_POST['Zip'] : null;
$country = isset($_POST['Country']) ? $_POST['Country'] : null;

$db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')");
if ($result == 1) {
    echo '{"success":true}';
} else {
    echo '{"success":false}';
}

//$sqlCheck = "INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')";

//echo json_encode($sqlCheck);


?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/) and for your sake I hope this is not on the public internet. You need to ensure any and all user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you are at serious risk of an application compromise. Whenever possible use prepared statements and placeholders to ensure you're not exposed to errors of that sort. [`ezSQL_mysql`](http://docs.phpvms.net/internals/d5/d95/classez_s_q_l__mysql.html) does have an `escape` function you **urgently** need to use.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn ooo thanks missed that! i added it to the form tag but still not inserting into the db :/

Comment: @tadman no its internal only. I need to get it functional and then fix security issues later. The boss just wants to get it out there so they can "play" with it

Comment: @maryjane9110024 That's a very bad idea. Just do it right the first time by using prepared statements and then you don't have to keep a log of all the places you need to go back over after it's ready to be "released". It takes NO extra time to do it right and could save you many hours further down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
```

The form element is **named** `main_form`. Your jquery selector is looking for an **id**. You can just change `name="main_form"` to `id="main_form"` on your form tag and it should fix it.

Comment: ooo thanks missed that! i added it to the form tag but still not inserting into the db :/ How do I print out the sql string to see if the variables are being passed? I tried `echo json_encode($sqlCheck);` but its not working.

Comment: Try opening developer tools in your browser (F12) and looking at the ajax request. You can see what variables are sent when inspecting the post request. You can also just print_r($_POST) in the processing page and see what was sent over. Looking at the ajax request, the response body would have that output.

Comment: Where do I put the print_r? In the webpage or php processing file? Also, I am not real familiar with the developer tools so how would I look at the ajax request. I'm poking aorund in there now but I can't find it. :(

Comment: Look at the network tab. In IE you will need to click the play triangle button to start recording the network traffic. Other browsers will just start showing the requests.